# Is there a way to find out who created a public folder in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Is there a way to find out who created a public folder in Exchange 2010?

I've tried looking in ADSI Edit and `Get-PublicFolderStatistics` (which gives created/modified dates and times).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange doesn't track a "Created-By" attribute for Public Folders. I've taken a dive into mfcmapi to see what was there under the hood, but there is no created-by attribute. The closest it gets is as Joeqwerty points out, the default rights it assigns upon creation.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the owner of the PF in Outlook. The person who created the PF is granted the Owner role on the folder.